# Direct access to Vector elements in a data.frame in R?

Tags: arrays, r, vector, types

Is it possible to directly access elements of vectors in a data.frame?

```
# DataFrame
nerv <- data.frame(
    c(letters[1:10]),
    c(1:10)
)

str(nerv)

# Accessing 5th element of the second variable/column
# This should give "5", but it does NOT work
nerv[2][5]

# Works, but I need to know the NAME of the column
nerv$c.1.10.[5]
```

I tried several things, but none of them worked. I just have the index of the column but not the name, since I want to interate several columns using a loop.

It seems that I have a basic knowledge gap and I hope you can help me to fill it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want:

```
> nerv[5,2]
[1] 5
```

The general pattern is `[r, c]` where `r` indexes the rows, and `c` indexes the columns/variables, that you want to extract. One or both of these can be missing, in which case, it means give me all of the rows/columns that do not have indexes. E.g.

```
> nerv[, 2] ## all rows, variable 2
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
> nerv[2, ] ## row 2, all variables
  c.letters.1.10.. c.1.10.
2                b       2
```

Notice that for the first of those, R has dropped the empty dimension resulting in a vector. To suppress this behaviour, add `drop = FALSE` to the call:

```
> nerv[, 2, drop = FALSE] ## all rows, variable 2
   c.1.10.
1        1
2        2
3        3
4        4
5        5
6        6
7        7
8        8
9        9
10      10
```

We can also use the list-style notation in extracting components of the data frame. `[` will extract the component (column) as a one-column data frame, whilst `[[` will extract the same thing but will drop dimensions. This behaviour comes from the usual behaviour on a list, where `[` returns a list, whereas `[[` returns the thing inside the indexed component. Some example might help:

```
> nerv[2]
   c.1.10.
1        1
2        2
3        3
4        4
5        5
6        6
7        7
8        8
9        9
10      10
> nerv[[2]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
> nerv[[1:2]]
[1] 2
```

This also explains why `nerv[2][5]` failed for you. `nerv[2]` returns a data frame with a single column, which you then try to retrieve column 5 from.

The details of this are all included in the help file `?Extract.data.frame` or `` ?`[[.data.frame` ``

Answer (score 7):

Since a data frame is technically a list, this also works:

```
nerv[[2]][5]
```

Answer (score 3):

try

```
nerv[5,2]
```

and...

```
?'['
```

This should help fill in your gap a bit.

Comment: I already tried `nerv[2,5]`, but it gives `NULL`. I also tried things like `as.vector(nerv[2])[5]`

Comment: That's back to front, rows first, columns second. You both have this the wrong way round.

Comment: @Gavin, I'm sure that @John made a typo... [fixed].

Comment: @aL3xa whoops sorry, should have grepped that. @John, sorry, didn't mean to be snappy.

Comment: I'm guessing I did make a typo... :) Thanks aL3xa